# perl regex to match string starting with pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have the below perl code. I am trying to set the `flag` to `1` if my `$location` has string `/foo/HELLO`, which is working fine. But now I want to set the `flag` to `0` if `$location` has `/foo/*` (it has `/foo/` and anything after it ***except HELLO***)

How can I frame my regex in `else` condition to achieve it?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $flag =0;

my @locations= (
  "/path/with/foo/HELLO",
  "/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.install",
  "/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.lintian-overrides",
  "/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.postrm",
  "/abc/def/ggfg",
  "/frgrg/hjytj/dgth",
);

foreach my $location(@locations){
   if ($location =~ m/\/foo\/HELLO/) {
       print 'match';
       $flag=1;
    } else {
      print 'no match';
      $flag=0
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Surely the `else` condition does that?

Comment: I tried to amend your question but I'm not sure I understand you. You say *"I am trying to set the `flag` to `0` if my `$location` has string `\foo\HELLO`"* and you say that it works. Yet your code sets `$flag` to 1 in that case. You then go on to say *"I want to set the `flag` to `0` if `$location` has `\foo\*`"* — do you mean `/foo/*`?

Comment: @Borodin : Updated the question. Sorry for confusion caused

Comment: You should also show the output that you require given the input data in `@locations`. You don't show and code that *uses* `$flag`, so it is hard to formulate a proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in `else`, so you already know it doesn't have `/foo/HELLO`. So just verify `/foo/` is still there:

```
} elsif ($location =~ m=/foo/=) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) and [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to construct a hash of the strings and the associated flag values:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my @locations= (
  "/path/with/foo/HELLO",
  "/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.install",
  "/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.lintian-overrides",
  "/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.postrm",
  "/abc/def/ggfg",
  "/frgrg/hjytj/dgth",
);

my %h = map { $_ =~ m|/foo/HELLO| ? ($_ => 1) : ($_=>0)  } grep {m|/foo/\w+|} @locations;

print Dumper \%h;
```

Now `%h`:

```
    {
      '/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.install' => 0,
      '/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.lintian-overrides' => 0,
      '/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.postrm' => 0,
      '/path/with/foo/HELLO' => 1
    };
```

Just change the regex's to suit what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're looking for is to filter those files that have `/foo/` but not `/foo/HELLO/` within the path. You can do that with the `grep` operator, as below

This code needs more work if your requirement is tighter than you describe. There are many edge cases and pitfalls here, and none of them are addressed. For instance, if the path contains `/foo/HELLONWHEELS` then it will be rejected, and that may or may not be your intention

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @locations= qw(
  /path/with/foo/HELLO
  /path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.install
  /path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.lintian-overrides
  /path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.postrm
  /abc/def/ggfg
  /frgrg/hjytj/dgth
);

say for grep m{ /foo/ (?!HELLO) }x, @locations;
```

**output**

```
/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.install
/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.lintian-overrides
/path/with/foo/def-abc-addons.postrm
```